# Apache Storm Error not able to submit topology on Localcluster

Tags: java, clojure, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I am using latest version of storm with below jars.

> storm-core-1.0.1
>
> storm-kafka-1.0.1
>
> zookeeper-3.4.8
>
> kafka_2.10-0.9.0.1

It is working fine with `storm-core-0.9.3` but throwing error with latest version of storm.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method clojure.lang.RT.classForNameNonLoading(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; from class org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$loading__5340__auto____6155
at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$loading__5340__auto____6155.invoke(nimbus.clj:16)
at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus__init.load(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5528)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at org.apache.storm.testing$loading__5340__auto____6153.invoke(testing.clj:17)
at org.apache.storm.testing__init.load(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.storm.testing__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5528)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:628)
at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5618)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster$loading__5340__auto____6151.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:17)
at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster__init.load(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you might be importing two different versions of the Clojure jar. If your project is Maven based, try running

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

This will produce a tree with all of your projects jar dependencies. Try to see if your detecting two different versions of the Clojure jar, and if so, which of your dependency is importing it.

Comment: I am using Clojure.1.6.0.jar with latest version of storm-core-1.0.1

Comment: Storm 1.0.1 is using Clojure 1.7.0, this might very well be the cause of your issue. [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.storm/storm-core/1.0.1)

Comment: @Re'em: thanks a lot for this answer and the specific comment about clojure v1.7.0!  I was totally stuck.